# Regex Pipe bar question in PHP

Tags: php, regex, pipe

I have a line of text that looks like "...X...Y...", where X and Y are both either Ok, Empty, or Open.  Using PHP, I'm trying to use preg_match() to figure out what each one is.

```
$regex = '/(Ok|Open|Empty)/';
preg_match($regex, $match, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

However, in the case that X is "Empty", and Y is "Ok", the following line gives me two matches: "Empty", and "Empty".

What's wrong with this regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`preg_match()` do only one match, the first it find. In your case the first is "Empty".

The array returned by `preg_match()` contains the text matching to your whole regex in the first slot `$matches[0]`.
For each group (the parenthesis) the next slots of `$matches` will contain the captured content. In your case you have one group, containing "Empty".

The result will be `$matches[0] == "Empty"` and  `$matches[1] == "Empty"`

---

To capture everything that matches your regex you have to use the `preg_match_all()` method.

```
<?php

$match = "test Open test Empty test";

$regex = '/(Ok|Open|Empty)/';
preg_match_all($regex, $match, $matches);
print_r($matches);

?>
```

The first slot will contain all the matching strings, and the second will contain the first captured group for each of these strings.

[The code on ideone](http://ideone.com/g7zTB)

---

**Resources :**

- [php.net - preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match)
- [php.net - preg_match_all()](http://php.net/preg_match_all)

Answer (score 0):

use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) for multiple results. The typical matches-array is constructed like this:

```
array(
    'Empty', // whole match
    'Empty'  // match group 1
)
```

You are only matching the first Ok, Open or empty, but since you use a match group, it appears twice.